# Is it possible to update an existing device driver to a new model of the same device?

Tags: device-driver, xorg

i have typically compiled a device driver for radeon from
 [GitHub Source](https://github.com/ahiliation/The-radeonhd-driver) 
  [Upstream Source](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/driver/xf86-video-radeonhd/)

but this driver did not detect my device.
here is a portion from /var/log/Xorg.0.log

```
    [  3766.775] (II) LoadModule: "radeonhd"
    [  3766.775] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/radeonhd_drv.so
    [  3766.775] (II) Module radeonhd: vendor="AMD GPG"
    [  3766.775]    compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.3.0
    [  3766.775]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
    [  3766.775]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 12.1
    [  3766.775] (II) RADEONHD: X driver for the following AMD GPG (ATI) graphics devices:
    [  3766.775]    RV505 : Radeon X1550, X1550 64bit.
    RV515 : Radeon X1300, X1550, X1600; FireGL V3300, V3350.
    RV516 : Radeon X1300, X1550, X1550 64-bit, X1600; FireMV 2250.
    R520  : Radeon X1800; FireGL V5300, V7200, V7300, V7350.
    RV530 : Radeon X1300 XT, X1600, X1600 Pro, X1650; FireGL V3400, V5200.
    RV535 : Radeon X1300, X1650.
    RV550 : Radeon X2300 HD.
    RV560 : Radeon X1650.
    RV570 : Radeon X1950, X1950 GT; FireGL V7400.
    R580  : Radeon X1900, X1950; AMD Stream Processor.
    [  3766.775]    R600  : Radeon HD 2900 GT/Pro/XT; FireGL V7600/V8600/V8650.
    RV610 : Radeon HD 2350, HD 2400 Pro/XT, HD 2400 Pro AGP; FireGL V4000.
    RV620 : Radeon HD 3450, HD 3470.
    RV630 : Radeon HD 2600 LE/Pro/XT, HD 2600 Pro/XT AGP; Gemini RV630;
        FireGL V3600/V5600.
    RV635 : Radeon HD 3650, HD 3670.
    RV670 : Radeon HD 3690, 3850, HD 3870, FireGL V7700, FireStream 9170.
    R680  : Radeon HD 3870 X2.
    [  3766.775]    M52   : Mobility Radeon X1300.
    M54   : Mobility Radeon X1400; M54-GL.
    M56   : Mobility Radeon X1600; Mobility FireGL V5200.
    M58   : Mobility Radeon X1800, X1800 XT; Mobility FireGL V7100, V7200.
    M62   : Mobility Radeon X1350.
    M64   : Mobility Radeon X1450, X2300.
    M66   : Mobility Radeon X1700, X1700 XT; FireGL V5250.
    M68   : Mobility Radeon X1900.
    [  3766.775]    M71   : Mobility Radeon HD 2300.
    M72   : Mobility Radeon HD 2400; Radeon E2400.
    M74   : Mobility Radeon HD 2400 XT.
    M76   : Mobility Radeon HD 2600;
        (Gemini ATI) Mobility Radeon HD 2600 XT.
    [  3766.775]    M82   : Mobility Radeon HD 3400.
    M86   : Mobility Radeon HD 3650, HD 3670, Mobility FireGL V5700.
    M88   : Mobility Radeon HD 3850, HD 3850 X2, HD 3870, HD3870 X2.
    [  3766.775]    RS600 : Radeon Xpress 1200, Xpress 1250.
    RS690 : Radeon X1200, X1250, X1270.
    RS740 : RS740, RS740M.
    RS780 : Radeon HD 3100/3200/3300 Series.
    [  3766.775]    R700  : Radeon R700.
    RV710 : Radeon HD4570, HD4350.
    RV730 : Radeon HD4670, HD4650.
    RV740 : Radeon HD4770. EXPERIMENTAL AND UNTESTED.
    RV770 : Radeon HD 4800 Series; Everest, K2, Denali ATI FirePro.
    RV790 : Radeon HD 4890.
    [  3766.776]    M92   : Mobility Radeon HD4330, HD4530, HD4570. EXPERIMENTAL.
    M93   : Mobility Radeon M93. EXPERIMENTAL AND UNTESTED.
    M96   : Mobility Radeon HD4600.
    M97   : Mobility Radeon HD4860. EXPERIMENTAL AND UNTESTED.
    M98   : Mobility Radeon HD4850, HD4870.
    [  3766.776] 
    [  3766.776] (II) RADEONHD: version 1.3.0, built from git branch master, commit 76cdcba6

    [  3766.776] (--) using VT number 7

    [  3766.779] (EE) No devices detected.
    [  3766.780] 
    Fatal server error:
    [  3766.780] no screens found
    [  3766.780] 
    Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
    for help. 
    [  3766.780] Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional     information.
    [  3766.780]
```

I think my model is radeon 7480 related.

Is there any way to extend the driver to radeon 7480 related?
I am a newbie to device driver programming.

here is part from lspci output

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Device 9993
```

Comment: Sure, get the programmer's manual of your card, learn how it works and start churning out code.

Comment: anyway thanks :) But i may come up with new questions